# Java Gradle: How to include external jars using java-plugin jar task?

Tags: java, build, gradle, dependency-management

```
apply plugin: 'java'

archivesBaseName = 'foo-client'
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
//version = '1.0'
dependencies{
    compile 'foo:bar:1.0-SNAPSHOT', 
            'foo:bar-common:1.0-SNAPSHOT', 
            'foo:bar-communication-api:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
repositories{ 
    flatDir{
        dirs '/lib'
    }
}
```

When executing the inherited `jar` task, this will create `foo-client.jar` in the `build/lib` directory of the project. What I need to do is include several jars to be put in that same directory, otherwise the project will not run correctly.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Gradle 1.1 the following did the trick,

```
apply plugin: 'java'

archivesBaseName = 'foo-client'
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

task copyToLib(type: Copy){
    into 'bar\\lib'
    from configurations.runtime
    from configurations.default.allArtifacts.getFiles()
}

dependencies{
    compile 'foo:bar-agent-dist:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT', 
            'foo:bar-common:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT', 
            'foo:bar-communication-api:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}


repositories{ 
    flatDir{
        dirs '/lib'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define the external jars as runtime dependencies and then use a copy task to copy them to build/lib, e.g.:

```
task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtime
    into "$buildDir/libs"
}
```